# BIND DNS (with IPA) unable to Forward DNS Requests

Tags: bind, centos7, freeipa

I have been trying to install IPA on my CentOS system for several days, but I keep experiencing a problem with DNS forwarding, in that I am unable to get it working. I have tried this with two DNS namespaces:

- ost.local
- ost.example.com (where example.com is a domain I own, but have minimal access to, a web administration panel points that exact domain via an A record to my public IP)

When I install IPA, and ask `ipa-server-install` to configure BIND as well, which it does. But, when it asks for the forwarders, I enter `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` (I have also tried with my Router and ISP DNS addresses), but I get the following:

```
Do you want to configure DNS forwarders? [yes]:
Enter the IP address of DNS forwarder to use, or press Enter to finish.
Enter IP address for a DNS forwarder: 8.8.8.8
DNS forwarder 8.8.8.8 added
Enter IP address for a DNS forwarder: 8.8.4.4
DNS forwarder 8.8.4.4 added
Enter IP address for a DNS forwarder: 
Checking forwarders, please wait ...
ipa         : ERROR    Forwarder 8.8.8.8 does not work
Forwarder 8.8.8.8 does not respond
```

The install exits at this point, but if I perform the install without configuring DNS forwarders, I am able to, but I get this error when I try to configure the DNS forwarders from IPA:

[image]

If I connect via `nslookup` (either locally, or remotely), I can query the local zone, but if I request a record outside of the zone, I get:

```
# nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> google.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.206.100

> server 127.0.0.1
Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
> directory.ost.example.com
Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53

Name: directory.ost.example.com
Address: 192.168.0.2
> google.com
Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find google.com: NXDOMAIN
```

here is `dig @127.0.0.1 google.com`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7_1.5 <<>> @127.0.0.1 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 3132
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; Query time: 1470 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 06 10:11:47 GMT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong?

---

My `named.conf` file looks like:

```
options {
        listen-on-v6 {any;};

        directory "/var/named";
        dump-file               "data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file         "data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file      "data/named_mem_stats.txt";

        forward first;
        forwarders { };

        allow-query { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/24; };

        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.0/24; };

        tkey-gssapi-keytab "/etc/named.keytab";
        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";

        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;

        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

dynamic-db "ipa" {
        library "ldap.so";
        arg "uri ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fslapd-OST-EXAMPLE-COM.socket";
        arg "base cn=dns, dc=ost,dc=example,dc=com";
        arg "fake_mname directory.ost.example.com.";
        arg "auth_method sasl";
        arg "sasl_mech GSSAPI";
        arg "sasl_user DNS/directory.ost.example.com";
        arg "serial_autoincrement yes";
};
```

---

### EDIT

here is a packet trace during an `nslookup` to `microsoft.com` via `127.0.0.1`, but it still reported nothing:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 53 -v
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
11:11:46.398533 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30233, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.44598 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 16053+ [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:46.398550 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30234, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    directory.ost.example.com.28345 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 1718+% [1au] A? microsoft.com. (42)
11:11:46.399423 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47839, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 66)
    directory.ost.example.com.49824 > router.domain: 62950+ PTR? 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
11:11:46.400157 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    router.25830 > directory.ost.example.com.domain: 18328+ [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:46.400675 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30235, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.61359 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 9755+% [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:46.400860 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    router.47804 > directory.ost.example.com.domain: 7806+% [1au] A? microsoft.com. (42)
11:11:46.401766 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 110)
    router.domain > directory.ost.example.com.49824: 62950 1/0/0 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. PTR google-public-dns-a.google.com. (82)
11:11:46.402049 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47840, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    directory.ost.example.com.46228 > router.domain: 16395+ PTR? 1.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
11:11:46.402586 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    router.dj-ice > directory.ost.example.com.domain: 51438+% [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:46.403149 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 91)
    router.domain > directory.ost.example.com.46228: 16395* 1/0/0 1.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa. PTR router. (63)
11:11:51.401318 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12713, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.33381 > google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain: 47813+ [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:51.401339 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12714, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    directory.ost.example.com.15062 > google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain: 31947+% [1au] A? microsoft.com. (42)
11:11:51.401501 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12715, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.21893 > google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain: 50112+% [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:51.401690 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47841, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 66)
    directory.ost.example.com.36630 > router.domain: 10373+ PTR? 4.4.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
11:11:51.403092 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    router.51126 > directory.ost.example.com.domain: 45362+ [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:51.403831 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    router.55917 > directory.ost.example.com.domain: 15092+% [1au] A? microsoft.com. (42)
11:11:51.404510 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    router.41956 > directory.ost.example.com.domain: 25944+% [1au] NS? . (28)
11:11:51.405130 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 110)
    router.domain > directory.ost.example.com.36630: 10373 1/0/0 4.4.8.8.in-addr.arpa. PTR google-public-dns-b.google.com. (82)
11:11:56.400719 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47842, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    directory.ost.example.com.domain > router.47804: 7806 ServFail 0/0/1 (42)
11:11:56.400754 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47843, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    directory.ost.example.com.domain > router.55917: 15092 ServFail 0/0/1 (42)
11:11:56.401898 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > directory.ost.example.com.28345: 1718 ServFail 0/0/1 (42)
11:11:56.402396 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain > directory.ost.example.com.15062: 31947 ServFail 0/0/1 (42)
11:11:56.402620 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47844, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.domain > router.25830: 18328 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.402630 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47845, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.domain > router.dj-ice: 51438 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.402655 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47846, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.domain > router.51126: 45362 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.402661 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 47847, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    directory.ost.example.com.domain > router.41956: 25944 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.403645 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > directory.ost.example.com.44598: 16053 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.403916 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > directory.ost.example.com.61359: 9755 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.404643 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain > directory.ost.example.com.33381: 47813 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
11:11:56.404844 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain > directory.ost.example.com.21893: 50112 ServFail 0/0/1 (28)
```

Comment: Tried to ping these DNS servers? Are they really available? Also I suggest you to try capturing DNS traffic and see what is going on wire.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov yes, they are available, and are returning correct results to nslookup when queried directly

Comment: Then it is worth looking into BIND logs, and also capturing what is going on tcp and udp 53 (DNS uses both, especially for ipv6 or dnssec).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I have attached some network capture. Btw, I went into `/etc/sysconfig/named`, and set `OPTIONS="-4"` (there was an error in `/var/log/messages`, but that was solved by that change)

Comment: I see that there were no single reply. Could it be SELinux blocking?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I don't think so, I have disabled SELinux (and firewalld), and it is still unable to forward connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, finally found the issue.

I am running this service behind a DD-WRT router, and on the router, there was an option (under `Setup` > `Basic Setup`) labelled `Forced DNS Redirection`. When I disabled this option, the `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` started responding again.